# Call another URL at the time of one video playing from url on iphone

Tags: iphone, url, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my application i'm playing 2 videos from array one after another.I want to hit another url at the time of first video begin to play without affecting the video playing.

**Here is my code what i have tried for playing two videos one after another,**

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender{    
i=0;
array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/adplayer/colgate.mp4",@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/ventuno-platform-flv-sep2010/happy_family.mp4",nil];
[self initializPlayer]; }
```

The above action event is called when user click on the button to start playing the videos.

```
-(void)initializPlayer{

if(i<[array count])     

    i +=1;
else {
    i = 1;
}

NSLog(@"i value:%@",[array objectAtIndex:i-1]);
NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:i-1]];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url1];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen=YES;
[moviePlayerController play];}
```

In initializPlayer method two videos are playing one after another, and also two notifications are there,first one is used to notify when the video completed or user press the done button.another one is used to notify,

1.videoplay
2.videopause
3.video Interrupted
4.videoforward
5.videobackward

```
 -(void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification{

NSLog(@"moviePlaybackComplete");
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController=[notification object];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
            object:moviePlayerController];

[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
[moviePlayerController release];
[self initializPlayer];}
```

moviePlaybackComplete notification is used to notify the user when the video is completed.

```
-(void) moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSLog(@"moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange");
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = notification.object;
MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = moviePlayer.playbackState;
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
{
    //NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped");
} 
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) 
{
    //NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying");
} 
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
{
    //NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused");
} 
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted) 
{
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted");
} 
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward)
{
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward");
} 
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward)
{
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward********");
}}
```

moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange notification is used to notify the user if any changes is made in playbackstate.

**MY DOUBT:**

At the time of first video playing(beginning) i want to hit another url without affecting the video.Hit one more url at the end of the first video.

Please Guide me to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Hai,The url with this kind:http://ventunotech.com/api/publisher/adResponse.php?vID=MCs1MzcwMXx8MzYxfHw0MA&status=start

Comment: Hai,Anyone please give me some ideas for call the url when another video start playing from url.Thank You

Comment: will the link that you want to fetch would be the link of the second video? why dont you fetch the links before playing the video, is it a requirement that the link has to be fetch when the video starts playing? if it is a requirement, why dont you fire another thread and fetch the url.